# How to cancel adapters notify?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Recyclerview adapter has various notify methods

```
notifyItemChanged(int)
notifyItemInserted(int)
notifyItemRemoved(int)
notifyItemRangeChanged(int, int)
notifyItemRangeInserted(int, int)
notifyItemRangeRemoved(int, int)
```

They adds events to queue which allows smooth animation, but if new notify, which reflects changes in datasize, is issued before previous event is completed then exception is thrown

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Tmp detached view should be removed from RecyclerView before it can be recycled
```

How to cancell unfinished notifies?

Comment: Are you trying to notify adapter from multiple (non ui) threads?

Comment: If you have some complex crazy updating, you might wanna take a look at DiffUtil, it offloads comparison process to a different thread and handles those calls for you

Comment: @Okas from retrofit callbacks which are on ui thread. but ocassionaly one arraives few miliseconds after previous one and i get that exception. Where rare event.

Comment: I dont think you can cancel recyclerview update cycle after it has started. Most probably you are encountering some recyclerview bug. Can you construct a test case?

Comment: I am having a similar issue, it is very difficult to replicate. @Yarh have you had any luck to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wait for the animation to complete and then execute a notification. This should help avoid your exception:

```
RecyclerView.ItemAnimator animator = mRecyclerView.getItemAnimator();
animator.isRunning(() -> {
    mAdapter.setItems(itemList);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanges();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also experiencing the same problem. I was also using `DiffUtil.calculateDiff()` method to smoothly update my `RecyclerView`. But in my case, as I understand, there were some pending updates when my `Activity` / `Fragment` was stopped, that were triggered after resuming to the screen.

What helped me to clear this pending updates is calling `adapte.notifyDataSetChanged` in `onStop`. Also with the help of `recyclerView.hasPendingAdapterUpdates` I was able to check if there were any pending updates.

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    if (recyclerView.hasPendingAdapterUpdates()) {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    super.onStop();
}
```

p.s. you cal also make sure that there is no `android:animateLayoutChanges=true` in your layout together with a `RecyclerView` and that you aren't using your `RecyclerView` inside a `NestedScrollView`.